# regex turkey phone number

Tags: regex, phone-number, regexp-replace, turkey-test

I am using the following expression for the mobile phone rule in google workspace. But this expression also includes landline phones. How do I prevent this? Also google workspace does not use this term "^" used at the beginning of the expression.

Mobile: 05xx xxx xx xx
Landline: 02xx xxx xx xx

```
\(?\+?(\d{2})?[ -]?([05]+\d{2})\)?[ -]?(\d{3})[ -]?(\d{4})?[ -]?(\d{2})[ -]?(\d{2})
```

Comment: Which of the 2 Turkish phone numbers are you targeting?

Comment: this 05xx xxx xx xx.

Also, since google workspace doesn't recognize these two expressions "^","$", it also blocks a list with an imei number.

Example: 490154203237518

Comment: Does it then implicitly anchor the expression so that the regex does not match in the middle of a longer string? That's what the anchors `^` and `$` are for.

Comment: Yes. Captured and blocked the imei of a phone list in google drive.

Answer (score 0):

```
(^05\d{2})(\s|-)?(\d{3})(\s|-)?(\d{4})
```

Comment: does not cover other uses.

05551234567 ----
5551234567 ----
905551234567 ----
+905551234567 ----
(123)5551234567  ----

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.